# Laravel 5.1 Module with multiple controllers

Tags: laravel, hmvc

I want to create module with number of controller like

Admin is Module name and have AdminController.
Admin module has another controller CategoryController, ProductController.
Now i wanted to use that controller as part of admin module How can i achive that using Artem-Schander/L5Modular

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Just FYI: l5-modular handles multiple controllers in the same module but  not via HMVC structure. The package is not designed for this approach

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong namespace in your CategoryController.php

It should be `namespace App\Modules\Admin\Controllers`

and not `namespace App\Modules\Admin\Controllers\Category`

---

working example:

routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('module' => 'Admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\Admin\Controllers'), function() {

    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
});
```

AdminController.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Modules\Admin\Models\Admin;

class AdminController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        die('admin controller');
    }
}
```

CategoryController.php:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use App\Modules\Admin\Models\Admin;

class CategoryController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        die('category controller');
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular/issues/3) you said, you have a blank page. Check your .env file for the debug option and set it to true. Than you should have a detailed debug output.

Comment: Still not resolved same issue blank page and no error in error log.
http://192.168.11.101:8000/admin/category
http://192.168.11.101:8000/category

Comment: if you have defined a RESTful Resource Controller like above, the blank page for ../admin/category is the correct behavior. This route calls the show action in the AdminController which (I guess) returns nothing ;)

The route ../category should call the index action in the CategoryController if the route is defined.

Just copy the content from my answer into your files. This is for sure a working example.

Comment: Its working now thanks for your support. Its work while i   Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');

Comment: glad to hear :)

would you mind to upvote/accept my answer

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue anyone here to help me out? Getting error Class app\Modules\Account\Controllers\SettingController does not exist. I have SettingController inside Account module and my route is Route::group(array('module' => 'Account', 'namespace' => 'app\Modules\Account\Controllers'), function()
{
    Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');
    Route::resource('account-setting', 'SettingController');
});

Comment: @Rikesh: take a look at the very first line in your SettingController. Does it have the correct namespace? It should be: `app\Modules\Account\Controllers\`

Comment: @GordonFreeman - Thanks mate!! Actually I got this solved, but now there is conflict between account/show & account/setting. Can you help me out? My new route is <?php

Route::group(array('module' => 'Account', 'namespace' => 'app\Modules\Account\Controllers'), function()
{
    Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');
    Route::resource('account/setting', 'SettingController');
});

Comment: @GordonFreeman - I know it can be solved by prefix, but is there any other option? Because adding prefix will increase lot of work to change route action every where.

Comment: @Rikesh: you don't have to use the RESTful Resource Controller if you don't need to. Just define all the routes by yourself ;)

Comment: @GordonFreeman - Yeah as you we are lazy devs :p so was thinking for the alternative but I guess that is the only solution to define all routes manually. Thanks mate for such a great modular plugin :)

Comment: @GordonFreeman - it seems that if we create module with underscore user_profiles etc, it does not naming correct controllers or module name. Can you some light on this?

Comment: @Rikesh: please add an issue to https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular/issues